# Meteor method not returning html to template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to show a alert warning for when a user first logs in, after their first login then I don't want this message shown. So I've created this method:

```
Meteor.methods({
'firstLogin': function() {
    if (Meteor.user().loggedInTimes === 0) {
        return '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible alertBar" role="alert"><br><button type="button" class="alertButton" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><b>Please take a few minutes to personalise your experience at SSAW by updating your <a href="/profile" class="alert-link hoverAlert">profile</a></b>. </div>';
    }
}
});
```

I call it in `Meteor.isClient` as:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.myHome.helpers({
    count: function(){
        var user = Meteor.user();
        //console.log(user);
        if (user) {
            Meteor.call('firstLogin');
        }
      }
  });
}
```

However this does not render any of the html from the method. How can I get the html alert message to appear?

This is the `template`:

```
<template name="myHome">
<div class="container">
    {{{ count }}}
    <div class="text-center">
        {{#if currentUser }}
            <h1 class="roboto">Hi{{ username }}</h1>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Meteor.call** is an async function so You will have to pass a callback function and return the result. This is what you need to change.

Here i am passing a callback function to **Meteor.call** with returned result or error from **firstlogin** method and returning the result if there are no error.

```
Meteor.call('firstLogin', function(error,result){
          if(!error){
              return result;
          }
    });
```

Also Use **Handlebars.SafeString** to return html from helper function

**Complete Helper Function**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var count;

  Template.myHome.onCreated(function(){
    var user = Meteor.user();
        //console.log(user);
        if (user) {
            Meteor.call('firstLogin', function(error,result){
                if(!error){
                   count = result;
                }
        });
    }
  }

  Template.myHome.helpers({
    count: function(){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(count);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: thanks.....the html is doesn't appear in the template, but I do see it output in the console.log().

Comment: Thanks....I had to assign the `result` to a variable and then return that value outside the method call to see the html displayed.